# Request for sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have to write a request on a oracle.
I have create a field which can contain 40 characters.
I have to fulfield it with data from 3 fields from 3 differents tables.
This is my rule:

field1 = field2+ " " + field3 + " " + field4

if my concatenation goes beyond 40 characters, this is what I have to do:

-field1= field2 + "'" + trunc the field3 for the concatenation to length 40 with a minimum 8 for this field+ "'" + field4

if it still goes beyond 40 characters, this what I have to do:

- field 1= Trunc the field2 for the concatenation to have 40+" "+ trunc the field3 to have 8+" " + field4

I have not succeded to write a such request.

Anyone to help.
I'm very new on sql request!!

Comment: For string concatenation, use ||; for truncating a string, use SUBSTR(). I'm voting for putting this on hold until you add some code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length for `field3` would be `40 - 2 - len(field2) - len(field4)`, but at least 8 characters, or at least the length of `field3` if it is shorter than 8, so it can be calculcated as:

```
greatest(least(8, lengthc(field3)), 38 - lengthc(field2) - lengthc(field4))
```

The length for `field2` can be calculated as:

```
least(lengthc(field2), 38 - x - lengthc(field4))
```

where `x` is the length for `field3`.

So the expression to get the value for `field1` would be;

```
substr(field2, 1, least(lengthc(field2), 38 - greatest(least(8, lengthc(field3)), 38 - lengthc(field2) - lengthc(field4)) - lengthc(field4)))
|| ' '
|| substr(field3, 1, greatest(least(8, lengthc(field3)), 38 - lengthc(field2) - lengthc(field4)))
|| ' '
|| field4
```

Comment: Thanks Guffa. I do noy understand the first substr. It seems to have more elements.

Comment: @user3438349: The third parameter for that `substr` is quite long. It's the second of the expressions above, where `x` is substituted with the first expression. As the length of `field2` depends on the length of `field3` that expression has to be repeated.

Comment: Thanks, Guffa. I'have tried your request and it works.

Comment: But I need to know how to process in wrap up sql request

Comment: @user3438349: That would be the easy part. See this question for an example of an update with a join: https://community.oracle.com/thread/401246